# how to programmatically turn on or off mouse filter in windows xp

Tags: c, windows

subject is to turn on or off mouse filter. I found all api's configuring mouse except mouse filter, where is it?

Comment: Mouse precision. Control Panel -> Mouse Settings -> third tab -> mouse precision/filter checkbox

Answer (score 0):

```
if (needToOff())
    {
        deb("mouse filter: off");

        mouseAccel.MouseSpeed = mouseAccel.MouseThreshold1 = mouseAccel.MouseThreshold2 = 0;
        SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMOUSE, 0, &mouseAccel, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
    }
    else
    {
        deb("mouse filter: on");
        mouseAccel.MouseSpeed = 1;
        mouseAccel.MouseThreshold1 = 6;
        mouseAccel.MouseThreshold2 = 10;
        SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMOUSE, 0, &mouseAccel, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
    }
```